# I want vertical space between my picture and paragraph, both horizontal and vertical spaces needed

Tags: spacing

{get rid of the graphics if needed]
 Can anyone show me how this can properly be written? How should I use paragraph? I'm honestly lost

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png}

\newcommand{\Lm}{\lim_{x\to 0}}
\newcommand{\sn}{\sin(x)}
\newcommand{\cs}{\cos(x)}
\newcommand{\tn}{\tan(x)}
\newenvironment{Theorem}[2][Theorem]{\begin{trivlist}
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}


\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
%If you want to title your bold things something different just make another thing exactly like this but replace "problem" with the name of the thing you want, like theorem or lemma or whatever

\begin{document}

%\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\filledbox}
%Good resources for looking up how to do stuff:
%Binary operators: http://www.access2science.com/latex/Binary.html
%General help: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics
%Or just google stuff

\title{Theorem 7 (University Calculus, Has)}
\author{Joshua Johnson}
\maketitle

\begin{Theorem}{7}
\begin{Large}
Prove the $\Lm \frac{\sn}{x} = 1$, using the Squeeze Theorem, and the Real Analysis, $\varepsilon$ - $\delta$ definition.
\end{Large}
\end{Theorem}



\begin{proof}
\textbf{Squeeze Theorem approach}

\paragraph{Let us imagine that we have a unit circle, this is used to determine an area inequality. \textit{Observe that if a unit circle is not used, a constant can always be factored out.}}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{e786f27043388adf175d27914c113d58.png}
\end{center}
\end{proof}


$\sn$


\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code has a lot of incorrect use of commands. For example, `\paragraph{}`.

Comment: Some words in the question body text would be good, instead of only in the title.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: `\paragraph{}` is like `\section{}`. You write `\paragraph{Title of paragraph}` and then you write the contents of this sub-division of your document. `Large` is not an environment. `\Large` is a font switch.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite hard to tell what you are trying to do but this code, while not that clean, is cleaner, I think. It isn't obvious where you want vertical or horizontal space to go, but you almost certainly do not want to create it with `\paragraph`. Note that 2 blank lines are just the same as 1, and that you do not need to alter the `\baselinestretch` if you do not abuse the font sizing commands. The size switches handle this for you automatically - if you need to adjust the stretch to compensate for a size change, then you are doing something wrong.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,graphicx}

\newcommand*{\Lm}{\lim_{x\to 0}}
\newcommand*{\sn}{\sin(x)}
\newcommand*{\cs}{\cos(x)}
\newcommand*{\tn}{\tan(x)}
\newenvironment{Theorem}[2][Theorem]{\begin{trivlist}
    \setlength{\parindent}{4em}
    \setlength{\parskip}{1em}
    \item[\hskip \labelsep\bfseries #1\hskip \labelsep #2.]\Large}{\end{trivlist}}

\begin{document}

  \title{Theorem 7 (University Calculus, Has)}
  \author{Joshua Johnson}
  \maketitle

  \begin{Theorem}{7}
      Prove the $\Lm \frac{\sn}{x} = 1$, using the Squeeze Theorem, and the Real Analysis, $\varepsilon$ - $\delta$ definition.
    \end{Theorem}

  \begin{proof}
    \textbf{Squeeze Theorem approach}

    Let us imagine that we have a unit circle, this is used to determine an area inequality.
    \textit{Observe that if a unit circle is not used, a constant can always be factored out.}

    \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[scale=0.65]{example-image-a}
    \end{center}
  \end{proof}

  $\sn$

\end{document}
```

`\paragraph{}` is a sectioning command just like `\section{}`, `\subsection{}` etc. To use it, you say

```
\paragraph{Sub-division title}
Sub-division content goes here.
```

[image: picture in proof following Large theorem statement]

Comment: I just want to put space between my paragraph and picture! :)

Comment: @Gon You say you want both vertical and horizontal space. How much vertical space? Is this a one-off case? If not, you should define a suitable environment. I don't understand what horizontal space is possible here.